# Why can't I run Docker on my Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, docker

I installed Docker on my Mac OSX machine (El-Capitan) using Homebrew.

But when I try to run it, it gives me the error shown below.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build unknown

$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.12.2, build 9371605 

$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I would suggest you get rid of that and get Docker for Mac from the Docker web site. Much easier to deal with. It handles some of the back end stuff for you that you have to do yourself with docker-machine.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to uninstall docker,  I hit this hurdle as well and on Mac, follow these steps

- Go to the application folder and click the docker icon
- wait for it to start
- Once the docker starts, you can run any docker command without any issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to start the Docker daemon first. Check the caveats section of `brew info docker-machine`.

```
$ brew info docker-machine
docker-machine: stable 0.12.2 (bottled), HEAD
Create Docker hosts locally and on cloud providers
https://docs.docker.com/machine
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/docker-machine.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✔, automake ✔
==> Requirements
Build: git ✔
==> Caveats
To have launchd start docker-machine now and restart at login:
  brew services start docker-machine
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  docker-machine start
```

Comment: That didn't work: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/f7b36cea6ad337f586521b2fdc8f1780

Comment: @SaqibAli Hmm, can you find any logs about it in Console?

Comment: See step 6 of _Create a machine_ at https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine.

Comment: Just Cmd+Space, then Docker, hit enter. See the whale start in taskbar. No need to manually create machines

Comment: @Robert That's if you have Docker for Mac. `docker-machine` is from Docker Toolbox, completely different software install and works differently.

Comment: I uninstalled Docker via HomeBrew and installed Docker for Mac instead. That made it work. Thanks @DanLowe and Robert